# Python. aiohttp_jinjia2. Асинхронный рендер шаблонов

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, jinja2

Копался в коде aiohttp_jinja2, нигде там не нашел асинхронный рендер шаблонов. Получается aiohttp_jinja2 реализует только дополнение для aiohttp. А сам асинхронный рендер?

И если aiohttp_jinja2 не реализует асинхронный рендер, то возможно ли сделать его другим каким-либо способом?

И как синхронный рендер с aiohttp_jinja2 скажется на производительности в таком случае?

Comment: В сравнении с длительностью операций ввода/вывода, рендеринг шаблонов мгновенен. Поэтому на производительности он не скажется и делать его асинхронным необязательно.

Comment: @Sergey, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Генерация html из шаблонов скорее всего ограничена CPU, а не IO и типичный объём работы не достаточен, чтобы отгрузить в пул процессов (`run_in_executor()`) для асинхронного выполнения.